# Django Dry approach to get_queryset

Tags: python, django

My app maps users to companies, so they can only see their companies data unless the user is_staff, which can see all.

I am writing the same query over and over again and would like to refactor it to use the dry approach.

The problem is that nothing gets returned. No error either

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class Site(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    ...

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    ...
```

views.py

```
def get_company(user):
    if user.is_staff:
        company = Company.objects.all().order_by('-name')

    else:
        company = Company.objects.get(id=user.company.id).order_by('-name')

    return company


class DashboardList(ListView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'sites/dashboard.html'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_company(self.request.user)
```

Comment: Should not it be `Company.objects.filter(id=user.company.id).order_by('-name')
` instead of `get()`?

Comment: Also note that assuming `company` is an FK from User to Company, `user.company` *is* the relevant company, so there's no point doing a query at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Company.objects.get(id=user.company.id).order_by('-name')
```

Is not a valid operation.  get returns a company object, not a queryset

Try filter instead of get

```
Company.objects.filter(id=user.company.id).order_by('-name')
```

It will be fine.  So you can refactor like this

```
def get_company(user):
    query = {}
    if not user.is_staff:
        query['id'] = user.company.id
    return Company.objects.filter(**query).order_by('-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to map userS to companIES you will need to use a many to many relationship, instead of a one to many. Now you are just stating that a user can have only one company associated, but a company can have many users associated. So doing a filter for a user's companies makes no sense. To fix it, your models.py should be:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    ...
```

and your view.py:

```
def get_companies(user):
    if user.is_staff:
        companies = Company.objects.all()
    else:
        companies = user.companies.all()

    return companies.order_by('-name')


class DashboardList(ListView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'sites/dashboard.html'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_company(self.request.user)
```